# View exceptions in Kotlin Compose for web

Tags: kotlin-multiplatform, kotlin-js, compose-web

I'm playing with jetpack compose for web to see if I suits my needs.

The development is great, however, when an error (exception) occurs the logs are displayed in the browser in an not developer-friendly way. I attach screenshot:
[image]

Is there a way to see the exepctions in Intellij or at least in a way that I can read them?

Thanks,